# Error Occurs to run local IIS in visual studio 2013 ultimate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, localhost, iis-8.5

I have configure the IIS server 8.5 in my windows 8.1. But when i tried to run my mvc project on Local IIS server an error occurs. A dialog box appears having the statement  "**cannot debug some of the code in process w3wp.exe[3276]. IntelliTrace code failed. The System cannot find the file specified. Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code succeeded**"
 What I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Check your App Pool on your IIS is set to Enable 32bit Applications to True, Rebuild your Project and try again.